# Updating all tables across db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
for all fields in database where fieldname = 'x' and field.value = y, set field.value = z
```

Is there way to accomplish this without using cursors in one statement?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty dangerous thing to do.

Comment: Don't forget to backup your database before you embark on this adventure.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty dangerous, but you may be able to accomplish it using dynamic sql.  First, query your database for the schema, table, and column to generate the sql for you, and then just run it.  Something like the below (may need some tweaking), assuming all the values you want to match and set are static, you may also want to wrap it in a transaction so you can back out if it doesn't work as expected (should be pretty easy to do)

```
DECLARE @statement  VarChar(Max)

SELECT @statement = COALESCE(@statement + ' ', '') +
                    'UPDATE ' + s.name + '.' + t.name +
                    ' SET ' + c.name + ' = ''some value''' +
                    ' WHERE ' + c.name + ' = ''match this'''
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'MyColumnName'

-- run our generated statement
EXEC (@statement)
```

If you do a `SELECT @statement` instaed of the **EXEC** you should be able to see your generated update statement to make sure it works, and should look somewhat like this (in a single line of course)

```
UPDATE someSchema.SomeTable1 SET MyColumnName = 'some value' WHERE MyColumnName = 'match this'
UPDATE someSchema2.SomeTable2 SET MyColumnName = 'some value' WHERE MyColumnName = 'match this'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will want to use a list of tablenames and loop over it with an update statement for each table.

This question is very similar to [this one about mysql.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483980/multiple-table-update-same-column-for-each-table)

The purpose of a good normalized database is to store each discrete piece of data in only one place. If you're finding the same data spread over multiple tables, you might want to reconsider your database design.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately I'm not permitted to modify the schema :\, but agreed!

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_msforeachtable
"update ? set x=z where x=y"
```

Comment: this will throw and error msg for all the tables without a column x but it will carry on and loop through all the tables. If you want to avoid the error messages you can include a test for the existence of the column in information_schema.columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1='UPDATE ? SET field.value = ''z''',
@whereand = 'AND fieldname = ''x'' and field.value = ''y'''
```

**Warning**

`sp_MSforeachtable` has a reputation for skipping tables.